# Coroutines best way to use

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to coroutines. SO I just wanted to know what is the best way to use them.

My scenraio/use case is I want to make a API call on `IO thread` and observe the results on `Main thread` and update the UI. Also when fragment's `onDestoryView()` is  called, then I want to cancel my job.

My fragment asks the presenter for some updates. So my presenter has a coroutine running like this -

```
class MyPresenter(view: MyView,
                          private val coroutineCtx: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) : CoroutineScope {

    private val job: Job = Job()
    private var view: MyView? = null

    init {
        this.view= view
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + coroutineCtx

    fun updateData() = launch{
        //repo is singleton
        val scanResult = repo.updateData()
        when(scanResult) {
        sucess -> { this.view.showSuccess()}
        }
    }

    fun stopUpdate() { 
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

In my repository,

```
suspend fun updateData(): Result<Void> {
   val response = API.update().await()
   return response
}
```

Am I using coroutines correctly? If yes, my `job.cancel()` never seems to work although I call it from fragment's `onDestroyView()`.

Comment: I've heard it is best practice to use `SupervisorJob` instead of `Job` as the root job of your coroutine scope.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are using coroutine correctly. A few notes:

- You don't have to pass `view: MyView` to the constructor, and assign its value to the property in `init` block. Instead you can mark `view` parameter in the constructor as `val` and it will became a property:

  ```
  class MyPresenter(private val view: MyView,
                    private val coroutineCtx: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) : CoroutineScope {

      // you can get rid of the next lines:
      private var view: MyView? = null
      init {
          this.view= view
      }

  }
  ```
- `launch` function returns a `Job`. You can add an extension function, e.g. `launchSilent`, to return `Unit` :

  ```
  fun CoroutineScope.launchSilent(
      context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
      start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
      block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
  ) {
       launch(context, start, block)
  }
  ```
- From my observation `job.cancel()` works correctly: when you invoke it a coroutine must stop. For example if we put some logs:

  ```
  fun updateData() = launch{
      Log.d("Tag", "launch start")
      val scanResult = repo.updateData()
      when(scanResult) {
          success -> { this.view.showSuccess()}
      }
      Log.d("Tag", "launch end")
  }
  ```

  And add some delay to the repo's `updateData()` function:

  ```
  suspend fun updateData(): Result<Void> {
     delay(5000)
     val response = API.update().await()
     return response
  }
  ```

  And, for example, in the fragment after invoking `presenter.updateData()` we call something like `Handler().postDelayed({ presenter.stopUpdate() }, 3000)` we won't see **"launch end"** log in the **Logcat**.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination. But I have a doubt. How do I specify the network call should run on IO and update ui on main thread. Currently in my implementation it is not so readable I think

Comment: By specifying `Dispatchers.Main` as Coroutine Context, you show that the coroutine is launched in the context of Main Thread. So you can run your UI login there (for example set test to TextView). In the coroutine you call suspend function `repo.updateData()`, it means the coroutine is suspended without blocking the Main Thread while the network call is executed.